# Workday Payroll Import_Payroll_Input how to check for errors

Tags: workday-api

I am using Workday’s  Payroll  “Import_Payroll_Input”  web service api  (in C#)  to do bulk uploads, I need to know if there is a way to see if any of the payroll inputs had errors during the process?
A prime example is, I uploaded 1000 rows of data but there was 13 rows with errors during the process, is there a way to pull that information back?

Thank you,

Bill O.

Answer (score 3):

`Import_Payroll_Input` returns a WID. With the WID, you query `Get_Import_Processes` to retrieve the status. Then you use `Get_Import_Process_Messages`  to retrieve the messages.

See [Workday Integration API](https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Integrations/v34.0/Integrations.html)